# Trying to convert a Data Extract file from UTF-16 to UTF-8

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, data-extract

I'm trying to send Data Extracts to our SFTP in the UTF-8 format and I keep getting an error. I created two data extract steps.

First one

- Extract Type: Data Extension Extract
- File Naming Pattern: utf8test-de.csv
- DECustomer Key: UTF8Test
- Has Column Headers

Second one

- Extract Type: Custom UTF16 to UTF8 Encoding
- File Naming Pattern: utf8test-de.csv
- Folder: (left blank)
- Input File Location: Safehouse

A lot of the documentation says to choose "File Conversion" but I don't have that in my options, I just have a lot of specific options for my Extract Types.

My first step runs fine, but I always error out on my second step to convert to UTF8.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Erik B, You have to work with Salesforce support in order to get ExtractType of File Convert enabled. It is not enabled by default.